# Getting an ID of HTML element to Controller

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have a button in View, i want its ID in Controller, how can i do that?

Please consider the code below:
VIEW:

```
      <%= form_tag :controller => :t_activities, :action => :index , :method => "get" do %>
      <input name="activitybtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="m<% scenario.id %>" value="Take Activity"/>
      <% end %>
```

CONTROLLER:

> def index
>
> @abc = params[:id]
>
> end

I know i am doing this wrong, Got no clue of Rails.

One more thing, the method specified is "get", yet "post" needs to be identified in routes, how can i change it in such a fashion that it ends up accessing get "t_activities/index" ?

Comment: use `hidden_field_tag` in your form.

Answer (score 2):

You need another field in your form with a `name` attribute of "id". Something like this, assuming I have the value correct:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="m<%= scenario.id %>" />
```

This value will show up as `params[:id]` in the controller.

As for your second question, if you just want to change the form method to match the route, simply change `method => "get"` to `method => "post"` in your example above. If you would rather change the route to match the form, it depends on what you already have set up. Please paste the relevant portion of your routes file into your question if this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

> Pass id in form hidden field tag.

---

```
  <%= form_tag {:controller => :t_activities, :action => :index }, :method => "get" do %>

    <%= hidden_field_tag "id_name", @scenario.id %>


          <input name="activitybtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  value="Take Activity"/>
          <% end %>
```

---

> Access that id in the controller as params[:id_name] in the controller.